# How to return a specific field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Here is my code, it searches the word 'test' through all documents in 'subs' collection and return them.
The thing is I just need two specific fields (id and name).

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('subs')

    .find({
      $text: { $search: 'test' },
    })
    .toArray((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new err();
      }
      res.json({
        length: result.length,
        body: { result },
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can use a projection:
`db.collection('subs').find({$text: { $search: 'test' }}, {name: 1 } )`.

Read more about it here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-_id-field-only

Comment: This is better answer than mine, and includes reference to official doc.

Comment: it still returns other fields as well!

Comment: @Fabdol Can you share what your document looks like?

Comment: Sure here is my document:
https://ibb.co/h8nFStB
and what I get:
https://ibb.co/NCr6trW
and my code:
https://ibb.co/JRyJxgV

Comment: What driver and version are you using? I tried on the shell and it works.

Comment: I am using mongoose and I should have added projection:{ }

Comment: I figured the driver you were using had a different syntax for projections, which is why I asked. Glad I was able to help in some way!

Answer (score 0):

you can set the fields you need in additional argument to the `find` method :

```js
db.collection('subs').find({
  $text: { $search: 'test' }
}, 
{ 
  name: 1, 
  otherColumn: 1 
}); // select only the "name" & the "otherColumn" column
```

The `_id` column is always returned by default, but you could disable it by adding `_id: 0`.

Hope this solve your question.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work.... it still returns other fields as well
Here are photos:
https://ibb.co/h8nFStB
what I get: 
https://ibb.co/NCr6trW
and my code: https://ibb.co/JRyJxgV

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer! :

```
.find(
      {
        name: { $in: ['Prison Break', 'Dexter'] },
        $text: { $search: 'kill' },
      },
      {
        projection: { name: 1 },
      }
    )
```